# Is there a way to publish a C# console app running on the .NET Framework with System.media Soundplayer?

Tags: c#, console-application, soundplayer

When I publish my app and run it, it says that it couldn't find the path to `sound.wav` file and it crashes.

I put my sound files into a `bin/Debug/sound` folder, and use it like this in my code:

```
public void OpenInventory()
{
    SoundPlayer inventory = new SoundPlayer("sound/selection2.wav");

    inventory.Play();

    try
    {
        var item = Item.itemList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Amount == 0);

        if (item != null)
        {
            Item.itemList.Remove(item);
        }

        var loot = Loot.lootList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Amount == 0);

        if (loot != null)
        {
            Loot.lootList.Remove(loot);
        }
     }
     catch
     {
         inter.InventoryArray();
         UseItem();
     }

     inter.InventoryArray();
     UseItem();
}
```

Comment: Put file in the Release folder instead.

Comment: Have you set a value on the file's CopyToOutputDirectory property?

Comment: no i havent done that, i'll do it, also what is the parth to Release folder ? do iahve to use (//Release/sound/Sound.wav) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the file as a resource and access it using a resource stream. Something like this:

```
strong resource name = "MyNamespace.Sound.selection2.wav";
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
var inventory = new SoundPlayer(stream);
```

To embed the WAV file, change "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" on the file properties in solution explorer.

The tricky part of using such embedded resources is figuring out the correct resource name. By default it uses a namespace-like name for the resource. So for example, if the default namespace for your app is "MyNamespace", the file is in a folder named "Sound", and the file is named "selection2.wav", then the resource will be named "MyNamespace.Sound.selection2.wav".

`GetManifestResourceStream`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=netframework-4.8#system-reflection-assembly-getmanifestresourcestream(system-string)

`SoundPlayer` stream constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#system-media-soundplayer-ctor(system-io-stream)

Embedded resource names: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resources/manifest-file-names